# Unable To Display Image using Fly-Latex

Tags: errors

I have setup a Fly Latex server which is running perfect. Now, I want to add images to it and whenever I add the image name using proper syntax, I always end up getting a box with the image name inside it. Below is the code -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\graphicspath{ {\home\pranav\} }

    \title{Cartesian closed categories and the price of eggs}
    \author{Jane Doe}
    \date{September 1994}
    \begin{document}
   \maketitle
    \textcolor[Blue]{Hello world!}
   It is so nice to see the world!
    \includegraphics{details.png}

\end{document}
```

I compiled the color package from CTAN and put it inside the texlivepackages directory but this is not working. Can someone please tell what is happening?

Comment: `{\home\pranav\} ` should be `{/home/pranav/} ` unless you have macros defined called `\home` and `\pravnav`

Comment: the color argument of `\textcolor` is not optional so `\textcolor{Blue}{...` not `\textcolor[Blue]{..`

Comment: Nope, it is still not working : (.

Comment: no but they would be enough to stop the example so hard to comment on anything else. what you describe usually means that `[draft]` option has been used but your example doesn't show that

Answer (score 1):

Your code produces

```
   { {\home \pranav \} } 
! Paragraph ended before \graphicspath was complete.
```

as the braces don't match (`\}` is the `}` character not a group end)

changing `\}` to `}`

It produces

```
! LaTeX Error: Undefined color model `Blue'.
```

as

```
\textcolor[Blue]{Hello world!}
```

should be

```
\textcolor{Blue}{Hello world!}
```

changing `[]` to `{}`  produces

```
! LaTeX Error: Undefined color `Blue'.
```

as the predefined colour is `blue`. Fixing that produces the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@b ->\home
```

as latex paths should use `/` as `\home` is the macro `\home` not a folder of that name.

so changing the path to

```
\graphicspath{ {/home/pranav/} }
```

it runs without error:

[image]

As you see the graohic is included. If you get a box with a filename, presumably your code is not like the example you show but is rather:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\graphicspath{ {/home/pranav} }

    \title{Cartesian closed categories and the price of eggs}
    \author{Jane Doe}
    \date{September 1994}
    \begin{document}
   \maketitle
    \textcolor{blue}{Hello world!}
   It is so nice to see the world!
    \includegraphics{details.png}

\end{document}
```

in `draft` mode which produces

[image]